# SMTP function will not send

Tags: smtp

I have created a code where the user will enter a email address which will then be checked against a database and confirmed its part of that database. That part works and it also ensures that the user has data input in the textbox. The thing I can't get to work is for the application to send the email. I have tried multiple versions reworking it each time and I have tried different ports to send the email through. A few of the ports function and try to send the email before the catch error appaers that says the email has failed to send. If anyone has a idea please let me know. Thank you!

Here is the code that I use when i get trying to send the Email;

```cpp
string mail = txtEmail.Text;
                     
            SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select COUNT(*) FROM AdminLogin where AdminEmail='" + mail + "'", strcon);
            DataTable tab = new DataTable();
            adapt.Fill(tab);

            strcon.Open();

            string email = "Select AdminEmail FROM AdminLogin where AdminEmail='" + mail + "'";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(email, strcon);

            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            Regex emailregex = new Regex(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!!#$%&'*+/=?)^_{|}~-]+)");
            Random rand = new Random();
            randomcode = (rand.Next(999999)).ToString();

            if (txtEmail.Text != "")
            {
                if (emailregex.IsMatch(mail))
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
                        {
                          
                                string from, to;
                                from = "apmckee11@gmail.com";
                                to = (txtEmail.Text).ToString();
                                MailMessage mess = new MailMessage();
                                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            NetworkCredential NC = new NetworkCredential
                            {
                                UserName = "apmckee11@gmail.com",
                                Password = "Password"
                            };
                            mess.To.Add(to);
                                mess.From = new MailAddress(from);
                                mess.Body = ("Your Reset Code is :" + randomcode);
                                mess.Subject = "Password reseting code!";
                                mess.IsBodyHtml = true;
                                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                            smtp.Credentials = NC;                         
                                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                                smtp.Timeout = 60;
                                smtp.Port = 587;
                                smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            try 
                            { 
                                smtp.Send(mess);
                                lblSent.Visible = true;

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                lblFail.Visible = true;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblWrong.Visible = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    lblWrong.Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMissing.Visible = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using C# and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-5.0) library.

Try adding this to your code and the error message should explain what the problem is. Update your question with the output you get.

```cs
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateTestMessage2(): {0}",
            ex.ToString());
    }
```

By the way, if you are using this library then you should switch to [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) because smtp is being obsolete as it's mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Yes i am using C#. I should have mentioned that earlier. I have tried this and i have looked at various forms of this method today trying to get a result but i am not getting any results. I added the code from above and other ways trying to display the error exception. i am not sure what i am doing wrong. i will continue to work on it but if theres anyone else that has idea, I'd appreciate the help.